# DynamoDB queries on Hierachical structures

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

On [this lecture](https://youtu.be/RLxWobyd2Tc?t=2216), the speaker gives two examples of Hierarchical Structures:

1. as **item collections**
   [image]
2. as **Documents** (JSON)
   [image]

Suppose it is needed to query for movies in which a particular actor appeared or the length of tracks, how would one proceed to achieve this?

I have a feeling that creating GSIs would work for the first case, but have no clue if it would be possible in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, regarding the second case, there would be no way to query per anything inside the Attributes object.

If a query of that sort is needed, an hierarchical structure as item collection would be the choice.